# Airflow View Logs error "No host supplied" only if task fails otherwise logs are Visible

Tags: logging, airflow

On Task failure state:
*** Log file does not exist: /home/polaris/.airflow/logs/etl_dag_gcp_walmart_stg/etl_items_pangaea/2020-06-17T13:02:17+00:00/2.log
*** Fetching from: http://:8793/log/etl_dag_gcp_walmart_stg/etl_items_pangaea/2020-06-17T13:02:17+00:00/2.log
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. Invalid URL u'http://:8793/log/etl_dag_gcp_walmart_stg/etl_items_pangaea/2020-06-17T13:02:17+00:00/2.log': No host supplied

On task success or task running state:
Logs are Visible
*** Log file does not exist: /home/polaris/.airflow/logs/etl_dag_gcp_walmart_stg/etl_items_pangaea/2020-06-17T13:02:17+00:00/2.log
*** Fetching from: http://sib-stg-usgm-client.wmt-mtech-search-dp-sib-stg.us-central1.us.walmart.net:8793/log/etl_dag_gcp_walmart_stg/etl_items_pangaea/2020-06-17T13:02:17+00:00/2.log

[2020-06-17 13:51:41,776] {taskinstance.py:655} INFO - Dependencies all met for

any ideas?

Comment: it's a local machine or deployed somewhere e.g on mesos?

Comment: Found lssue in Apache Airflow. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-4922 if the task hard crashes then this could occur. After reviewing our own plugin code I noticed a sys.exit() was being used. I changed to raise AriflowException and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

restart celery and fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

1. Rerun (delete) the task, if possible, to see if logs show up
   This will clear/reset tasks and prompt them to run again
2. Change the log_fetch_timeout_sec to something more than 5 seconds (default)
   This is the amount of time (in seconds) that the Webserver will wait for an initial handshake while fetching logs from other workers.
3. Give your workers a little more power.
   If you're using Astronomer, you can do this in the Configure tab of the Astronomer UI.